# Full-height sidebar in Responsive Layout

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, sidebar

I am trying to create a responsive layout with a full height sidebar. On desktop the sidebar should float left of the main content and on tablet/mobile, the sidebar should overlap the main content (when activated). I have managed to get this layout working fine for desktop, although I am using the background-color of the main content to make it "look" like the sidebar is full-height, which is not ideal, but can't seem to wrap my ahead around how to get this working for tablet/mobile. See pic to better explain what I am trying to accomplish. When window is shrunk down less than 980px, the body seems to want to stay at 980. Any help would be very appreciated
[image]

```css
#sidebar {
  background: #FFF8DC;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-right: -300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#main-content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 300px;
  background: #2373DE;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  #main-content {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebar {
    z-index: 9;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="sidebar">
    sidebar stuff
  </section>

  <section id="main-content">
    main content stuff
    <footer>
      footer stuff
    </footer>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for making sidebar fixed on left side with 100% screen height and main-content with scrolling. You can change the properties (width, margin-left) of sidebar and main-content inside the media query to get the desired layout.

```css
#sidebar {
  background: #FFF8DC;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
}

#main-content {
  margin-left: 300px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    width: 200px;
  }
  #main-content {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="sidebar">
    sidebar stuff
  </section>

  <section id="main-content">
    main content stuff
    <footer>
      footer stuff
    </footer>
  </section>
</body>
```